# Python 2 : Dealing with String

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to get infomation about my machine's disk and i'am using psutil to do that. But the result not so friendly. So i decide to handle it but my code look so silly.

```
oldstr = str(psutil.disk_partitions())
oldstr = oldstr.replace("sdiskpart(", "")
oldstr = oldstr.replace(")", "")
oldstr = oldstr[1:-1]
oldstr = oldstr.split(",")
```

And the result look like below :

```
["device='C:\\\\'", " mountpoint='C:\\\\'", " fstype='NTFS'", " opts='rw", "fixed'", " device='D:\\\\'", " mountpoint='D:\\\\'", " fstype='NTFS'", " opts='rw", "fixed'"]
```

The most result i expect is like this :

```
["C:\\", "C:\\", "NTFS", "rw, fixed", "D:\\", "D:\\", "NTFS", "rw, fixed"]
```

Does anybody have a better idea ?
Please share with me your idea.
Many thanks,
Quang

Comment: Why are you converting it to a string? You can do `partitions = psutil.disk_partitions()`. And then access the values like `partitions[0].device`. Take a look at the [documentation](http://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.disk_partitions).

Comment: If i do as you say, each values will look like thís **sdiskpart(device='C:\\', mountpoint='C:\\', fstype='NTFS', opts='rw,fixed')** but i don't need "sdiskpart(". I just want the values between ' ' or device='C:\\' for example.

Comment: Had you even try it? I mean, if you access `partitions[0].device` you will get `'C:\\'`. Look at the documentation posted in the previous comment and [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). I don't have a Windows machine to see the exact output, but I've just tried it in Linux and it works.

Comment: Sorry Jose A, i haven't try it. I just guess and i don't read your answer carefully. Sorry for that and Thanks for your answer too,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ideally shouldn't be converting the result from `psutil.disk_partitions()` to a string and then parsing it. Instead what it returns is an object of `sdiskpart()` with the members being `['device','mountpoint','fstype','opts']`

Here's a naive solution:

```
final_result = []
part_results = psutil.disk_partitions()
for disk in part_results:
    final_result.append(disk.device)
    final_result.append(disk.mountpoint)
    final_result.append(disk.fstype)
    final_result.append(disk.opts)

# Some of these results could be '' (Empty Strings)
# Strip them out as required.
print final_result
```

You'll now have the result you expected

```
["C:\\", "C:\\", "NTFS", "rw, fixed", "D:\\", "D:\\", "NTFS", "rw, fixed"]
```

---

A alternative is as follows which returns a list of `OrderedDict`:

```
part_results = [part.__dict__ for part in psutil.disk_partitions()]
```

You can then loop among the key, value pairs and append them to an array as required. Here's a sample output for the above line of code.

```
[OrderedDict([('device', 'C:\\'), ('mountpoint', 'C:\\'), ('fstype', 'NTFS'), ('opts', 'rw,fixed')]),
OrderedDict([('device', 'D:\\'), ('mountpoint', 'D:\\'), ('fstype', 'NTFS'), ('opts', 'rw,fixed')])]
```

Comment: This is not correct in Python 3.6.3, psutil 5.4.0. `AttributeError: 'sdiskpart' object has no attribute '__dict__'`. This can be achieved with `part_results = [part._asdict() for part in psutil.disk_partitions()]`

Comment: Jose A, Agreed. but the Question says `Python 2` in the header. In either case, would you like to make an edit in the answer for `Py3`. I'd be more than happy to accept it?

Answer (score -2):

What about adding:

```
oldstr = [i.split('=') for i in oldstr]
oldstr = [x[1] if len(x) == 2 else x[0] for x in oldstr]
```

then resut will look like:

```
["'C:\\\\'", "'C:\\\\'", "'NTFS'", "'rw", "fixed'", "'D:\\\\'", 
"'D:\\\\'", "'NTFS'", "'rw", "fixed'"]
```

Comment: This is not a recommended approach. The result is an object and should be processed using the members of the object than by converting them to strings and performing string manipulation operations.